# SSRS Report Viewer Control Parameter alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am having problem aligning parameters in ssrs report viewer control ,is there any way i can control the display of the parameters in left side alignment or right side alignment. please see the below pic for more details.

These reports are hosted in sql server 2012 and processing mode is Remote.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the markup?

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and yes,i have full access to report server and reportserver.config file.Please let me know what can be done.

Comment: By markup I meant the ASPX page and its code.

Comment: is there any specific property in report viewer that alter the alignment of the parameters on the report control?   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer"  runat="server"  Font-Size="10pt" CssClass="reportviewer" KeepSessionAlive="true"
                ShowBackButton="true"
                ShowDocumentMapButton="true"
                ShowCredentialPrompts="false"
                ShowPageNavigationControls="true"
                ShowToolBar="true"
                ShowPrintButton="true"
                ShowWaitControlCancelLink="true"
                ShowReportBody="true"  </rsweb:ReportViewer>

Comment: Oh shoot, it's a component control. I'm not sure if there's a property there to change the behavior. Try this: open the report in IE, hit F12 to open the developer window, click on the cursor icon, and then click on the item you want to change the alignment for. Then under styles, look for either `padding` or `margin`, see if they're set.

Comment: I did every thing you mentioned but nothing helps , i am also working with Microsoft Help to fix this issue.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/684b831d-c3be-4afa-ae4f-9821fb4a1564/ssrs-report-viewer-control-parameter-alignment?forum=sqlreportingservices   , if any body got any other ides please do share with me.